# Opencart Login Admin Page Dont Open

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart-3

I´m having a problem with opencart. During today when I tried to login to administration the website simples load and stay at home.

I try to open https://mywebsite.com/admin and the link load, the page refresh and stay in homepage of the store but with the same URL: https://mywebsite.com/admin

I have tried to rename the htaccess file but the same happens.

.htaccess:

## php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml

## php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Again: The problem is that I try to go to administration and the website load but stay in homepage of the store.

Thanks

Comment: what is the content of config.php? admin/config.php

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a site with much/any traffic yet then start by renaming the .htaccess to .htaccess.txt through FTP/cPanel or what ever you choose. OpenCart does not require htaccess to operate, only for php setting tweaks and url rewriting on Apache servers (or others that are patched for htaccess support etc...)

If you are still seeing the main home page then as mentioned before its likely you have the config files setup incorrectly. Without knowing what version you run it is hard to advise.

Your config for the site front end has 2 defined values:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.mystore.com/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.mystore.com/');
```

These should ONLY match the main store url (no admin part)

Under recent OC versions and the latest dev you have these in the admin config:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.mystore.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.mystore.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.mystore.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.mystore.com/');
```

Now you can see that both URLS are there for the front and admin area - they may have got mixed up, so just check against that above to see which should be catalog side and which admin.

Other than the obvious above check some of the other basic debugs:

- Can you visit other pages like a product page ok?
- Try visiting the admin dashboard - does this put you back to the home page again or the login page?

  https://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard - change to your url!
- Lastly (sorry I am running out of time) has your host upgraded PHP versions and you run an old OpenCart version? This may also have caused an issue.

And FYI - OpenCart has a FREE support desk at https://support.opencart.com

Hope this helps!